# "Run-time error 9" when copying rows from one sheet to others

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Using Excel 2007, and trying to pull together VBA that will copy rows from a sheet called Forecasts in to various existing worksheets, where the worksheet name matches the value A2:A in Forecasts sheet.

When I run the below I get Run-time error 9, and debug mode highlights the following line

```
Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & rngCell.Value)
```

Complete code is:

```
Sub Retrieve_Forecasts()

Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngBurnDown As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strPasteToSheet As String

'Used for the new worksheet we are pasting into
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As Range

'Define the worksheet with our data
Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Forecasts")

'Dynamically define the range to the last cell.
'If we are not starting in A1, then change as appropriate
Set rngBurnDown = objWorksheet.Range("A2:A" & objWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'Now loop through all the cells in the range
For Each rngCell In rngBurnDown.Cells

    objWorksheet.Select

    If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
        'select the entire row
        rngCell.EntireRow.Select

        'copy the selection
        Selection.Copy

        'Now identify and select the new sheet to paste into
        Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & rngCell.Value)
        objNewSheet.Select

        'Looking at your initial question, I believe you are trying to find the next     available row
        Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.Range("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)


        Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

Next rngCell

objWorksheet.Select
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Click the Debug button and in the VBA editor hold the mouse over `rngCell.Value` on that line - what is its value?

Comment: Basically - he can't find the sheet which you are trying to access through ("Sheet" & rngCell.Value) . Check your sheet names and make sure that the sheet really exists in the workbook.

Comment: @paulbica - rngCell.value = "10000001" which matches Sheet4(10000001) in the project viewer

Comment: Your code is trying to activate a sheet named "Sheet10000001"

Comment: @paulbica Major head slap moment, I'll remove the "Sheet" & see how it goes, thanks for your help.

Comment: Removing "Sheet" from your statement will not fix the problem: it will try to activate sheet at index 10000001 (and you don't have a total of 10000001 sheets) - you need to determine the logic that will work with the specific sheet where you want to paste the data

Comment: Changes worked thanks @paulbica

Comment: It might be useful for others if you provide the working code in a new answer

Answer (score 0):

code was trying to activate a sheet named "Sheet10000001", worksheet title was simply "10000001".

Amended code

```
Sub Retrieve_Forecasts()

Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngBurnDown As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strPasteToSheet As String

'Used for the new worksheet we are pasting into
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As Range

'Define the worksheet with our data
Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Forecasts")

'Dynamically define the range to the last cell.
'If we are not starting in A1, then change as appropriate
Set rngBurnDown = objWorksheet.Range("A2:A" & objWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'Now loop through all the cells in the range
For Each rngCell In rngBurnDown.Cells

objWorksheet.Select

If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
    'select the entire row
    rngCell.EntireRow.Select

    'copy the selection
    Selection.Copy

    'Now identify and select the new sheet to paste into
    Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(rngCell.Value)
    objNewSheet.Select

    'next available row
    Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.Range("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)


    Range("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next rngCell

objWorksheet.Select
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub`
```

tested and working.